# lattice puzzles in the Constant Propagation for hotspot

Tags: math, compiler-optimization, jit

I read a article below about Constant Propagation for hotspot through lattice .
http://www.cliffc.org/blog/2012/02/27/too-much-theory-part-2/
And it described that " (top meet -1) == -1 == (-1 meet top), so this example works.  So does: (1 meet 2,3) == bottom == (2,3 meet 1).  So does: (0 meet 0,1) == 0,1 == (0,1 meet 0)"

However I cannot understand why  (top meet -1)==1 , and (-1 meet top)==-1? also why (1 meet 2,3) and (2,3 meet 1)==bottom  ? how the meet  is calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jacky, from your question it seems that you don't get some basic concepts. Have you tried to read linked [Lattice wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28order%29) article?

I'm not sure if I can be better than collective mind of the Wiki but I'll try.

Let's start with **poset** aka "Partially ordered set". Having a "poset" means that you have a set of some objects and some comparator `<=` that you can feed two objects to and it will say which one is less (or rather "less or equal"). What differs partially ordered set from totally ordered one is that in more usual totally ordered set at least one of `a <= b` and `a >= b` holds true. In "partially ordered" mean that both might be false at the same time. I.e. you have some elements that you can't compare at all.

Now **lattice** is a structure over poset (and potentially not every poset can be converted to a lattice). To define a lattice you need to define two methods **`meet`** and **`join`**. `meet` is a function from a pair of elements of the poset to an element of the poset such that (I will use `meet(a, b)` syntax instead of `a meet b` as it seems to be more friendly for Java-developers):

1. For every pair of elements `a` and `b` there is an element `inf` = `meet(a,b)` i.e. meet is defined for every pair of elements
2. For every pair of elements `a` and `b` `meet(a,b) <= a` and `meet(a,b) <= b`
3. For every pair of elements `a` and `b` if `inf = meet(a,b)` there is no other element `c` in the set such that `c <= a` AND `c <= b` AND NOT `c <= inf` i.e. `meet(a,b)` defines the largest common minimum element (or more technically an `infimum`) and such element is unique.

The same goes for `join` but the `join` is finding "maximum" of two elements or more technically `supremum`.

So now let's go back to the example you referenced. The poset in that example contains of 4 types or rather layers of elements:

1. `Top` - an artificial element added to poset such that it is greater than any other element
2. Single integers
3. Pairs of neighbor integers (range) such as "`[0, 1]`" (here unlike the author I will use "`[`" and "`]`" to define ranges to not confuse with application of `meet`)
4. `Bottom` - an artificial element added to poset such that it is less than any other element

<strike>Note that all elements in single layer are ***not comparable***(!) but all elements in any higher layer are greater than all elements in any lower layer. So no `1` is not less than `2` under that poset structure but `[1,2]` is less than both `1` and `2`.</strike>

Note that all elements in single layer are ***not comparable***(!). So no `1` is not less than `2` under that poset structure but `[1,2]` is less than both `1` and `2`. `Top` is greater than anything. `Bottom` is less than anything. And range `[x,y]` is comparable with raw number `z` if and only if `z` lines inside the range and in that case range is less, otherwise they are not comparable.

You may notice that the structure of the poset "induces" corresponding lattice. So given such structure it is easy to understand how to define the `meet` function to satisfy all the requirements:

1. `meet(Top, a)` = `meet(a, Top)` = `a` for any `a`
2. `meet(Bottom, a)` = `meet(a, Bottom)` = `Bottom` for any `a`
3. `meet(x, y)` where both `x` and `y` are integers (i.e. for layer #2) is either:

   - Just `x` if `x` = `y`
   - Range `[x, y]` if `x` + 1 = `y`
   - Range `[y, x]` if `y` + 1 = `x`
   - `Bottom` otherwise

   (I'm not sure if this is the right definition, it might always be range `[min(x,y), max(x,y)]` unless `x` = `y` . It is not clear from examples but it is not very important)
4. `meet([x,y], z)` = `meet(z, [x,y])` where `x`, `y`, and `z` are integers i.e. `meet` of an integer (layer #2) and range (layer #3) is:

   - Range `[x, y]` if `x` = `z` or `y` = `z` (in other words if `[x,y] < z`)
   - `Bottom` otherwise

   So `meet` of a range and an integer is almost always `Bottom` except most trivial cases
5. `meet(a, b)` where both `a` and `b` are ranges i.e. `meet` of two ranges (layer #3) is:

   - Range `a` is `a` = `b`
   - `Bottom` otherwise

   So `meet` of two ranges is also `Bottom` except most trivial cases

What that part of example is about is actually about "inducing" the lattice from the structure and verifying that most of the desirable features hold (except for symmetry which is added in the next example).

Hope this helps

---

**Update** (answers to comments)

It is hard to answer "why". This is because the author build his poset in that way (probably because that way will be useful later). I think you are confused because set of natural numbers has a "natural" (pun not intended) sort order that we all are used to. Put there is nothing that could prohibit me to get the same set (i.e. the same object = all natural numbers) and define some other sorting order. Are you familiar with `java.util.Comparator` interface? Using that interface you can specify any sorting rule for `Integer` type such as "all even numbers are greater than all odd ones and inside even or odd classes works "usual" comparison rule" and you can use such a `Comparartor` to sort collection if for some reason such sorting order makes sense for your task. This is the same case, for author's task it makes sense to define an alternative (custom) sorting order. Moreover he want to make it only a partial order (which is impossible with `Comparator`). An the way he defines his order is the way I described.

> Also if it is possible to do compare for [1,2] with 0 or 3?

<strike>Yes, you can compare and the answer directly follows from "all elements in single layer are not comparable(!) but all elements in any higher layer are greater than all elements in any lower layer": any number such as `0`, `3`, `42` or `Integer.MAX_VALUE` from layer #2 is greater than any range (layer #3) including the `[1,2]` range.</strike>

After some more thinking about it, my original answer was wrong. To satisfy author's goal range `[1,2]` should be not comparable with `0` or `3`. So the answer is ***No***. Actually my specification of the `meet` is correct but my description of sorting order is wrong.

> Also the explanation for top and bottom are different from you, the original author explained that "bottom” == “we don’t know what values this might take on , “top” == “we can pick any value we like", I have do idea if you both explanation for the top and bottom actual refer to the same thing.

Here you mix up how the author defines `top` and `bottom` as a part of a mathematical structure called "lattice" and how he uses them for his practical task.

What this article is about is that there is an algorithm that analyses code for optimization based on "analyses of constants" and the algorithm is build upon the lattice of the described structure. The algorithm is based on processing different objects of the defined poset and involves finding `meet` of them multiple times. What the quoted answer describes is how to interpret the final value that algorithm produces rather than how those values are define.

AFAIU the basic idea behind algorithm is following: we have some variable and we see a few places where the value is assigned to it. For various optimizations it is good to know  what it the possible range of values that the variable can take without running the actual code with all possible inputs. So the suggested algorithm is based on a simple idea: if we have two assignments (probably conditional) to the variable and in the first we know that values are in range `[L1, R1]` and in the second one values are in the range `[L2, R2]`, we can be sure that now value is in the range `[min(L1, L2), max(R1, R2)]` (and this is effectively how `meet` is defined on that lattice). So now we can analyze all assignments in a function and to each assign range of possible values. Note that this structure of numbers and unlimited ranges also forms a lattice that the author describes in the first article (http://www.cliffc.org/blog/2012/02/12/too-much-theory/).

Note that `Top` is effectively impossible in Java because it provide some guarantees, but in C/C++ as the author mentions, we can have a variable that is not assigned at all and in such case C Language standard allows the compiler to treat that variable as having any value *by compiler's choice* i.e. compiler might assume whatever is most useful for optimization and this is what `Top` stands for. On the other hand if some value comes in as a argument to a method, it is `Bottom` because it can be any value *without any control by compiler* i.e. compiler can not assume anything about the value.

In the second article author points out that although the lattice from the first article is good theoretically in practice it can be very inefficient computationally. Thus to simplify computations he reduces his lattice to a much simpler one but the general theory stays the same: we assign ranges to the variables at each assignment so later we can analyze code and optimize it. And when we finished computing all the ranges, the interpretation for optimization assuming that analyzed line is `if` in the:

```
if (variable > 0) { 
   block#1
} 
else { 
   block#2 
}
```

is following

- `Top` - if the line of code might be optimized assuming the variable has some specific value, compiler is free to do that optimization. So in the example compiler is free to eliminate that branch and decide that code will always go to block#1 and remove block#2 altogether OR decide that code will always go to block#2 and remove block#1 whichever alternative seems better to the compiler.
- `x` - i.e. some constant value `x` - if the line of code might be optimized assuming the variable has value exactly `x`, compiler is free to do that optimization. So in the example compiler can evaluate `x > 0` with that constant and leave only the code branch that corresponds to the calculated boolean value removing the other branch.
- `[x, y]` - i.e. range from `x` to `y`. If the line of code might be optimized assuming the variable has value between `x` and `y`, compiler is free to do that optimization. So in the example if `x > 0` (and thus `y > 0`), then compiler can remove block #2; `y <= 0` (and thus `x <= 0`) , then compiler can remove block #1; if `x <= 0` and `y > 0` compiler can't optimize that code
- `Bottom` - compiler can't optimize that code.

Comment: thank you for your detail explanation, can you kindly help to explain why" all elements in single layer are not comparable(!) but all elements in any higher layer are greater than all elements in any lower layer. "? Also if it is possible to do compare for [1,2] with 0 or 3?

Comment: Also the explanation for top and bottom are different from you, the original author explained that "bottom” == “we don’t know what values this might take on , “top” == “we can pick any value we like", I have do idea if you both explanation for the top and bottom actual refer to the same thing.

Comment: @Jacky, I thought a bit more about your questions and actually my original answer and my update were wrong in respect to " if it is possible to do compare for [1,2] with 0 or 3?". Please, see my updated answer.

Comment: @ SergGr, Noted, thank you so much for your kindly help , I need some time to learn from your answer, and response to you.

Comment: Can help to point out which sentences\segments that  the original author express or implied  the meaning that that " all elements in single layer are not comparable(!).... And range [x,y] is comparable with raw number z if and only if z lines inside the range and in that case range is less, otherwise they are not comparable." ? as I failed to figure it out.

Comment: @SergGrAlso ,also the author pointed out that " (0 meet 0,1) == 0,1 == (0,1 meet 0)" and "(1 meet 1,2) == 1,2 == (1,2 meet 1) ", which also doesn't match the requirements 4 you given above,  so it seems meet([x,y], z) not necessary equal to meet(z, [x,y]).

Comment: Another issue :meet([x,y], z) = Range [x, y] when   if x = z or y = z based your requirement 4 , then meet([0,1], 0)=Range [0, 1]  , as meet([0,1], 0)=1 based on the original author described, so Range [0, 1]=1,  based on your described above that "[1,2] is less than both 1 and 2" , then the  Range [0, 1] should also less than both 0 and 1, however here we calculated that the Range [0, 1]=1.

Comment: @Jacky, I'm not sure where you get "meet([0,1], 0)=1" in the article. The only similar statement I see is "(0 meet 0,1) == 0,1 == (0,1 meet 0)" which is in my notation `meet(0, [0,1])`  == `[0, 1]` == `meet([0,1], 0)`. And actually both examples (this  and  "(1 meet 1,2) == 1,2 == (1,2 meet 1) ") are examples of the fact `meet([x,y], z) == meet(z, [x,y])`

Comment: @Jacky, one more comment, I think you tried to understand that article from wrong direction: you are trying to understand technical details and then from them synthesize general idea. From my experience the right way is to get the general idea (i.e. what is the goal) first, and then dive into technical details. Those low-level details are usually much easier to understand if you keep the high-level goal in mind.

Comment: As to where the author  express or implied the meaning that that "all elements in single layer are not comparable(!)" is his  "As before if we try to merge (meet) a lattice element of X with X+1 we’ll make a short range". If `X` and `X+1` were comparable, `meet(X, X+1)` would be `X` not `[X, X+1]`

Comment: Very appreciate for your great suggestions and you are so kindly. I tried to see if I have other questions and response to you.

Comment: For requirement 3 "I'm not sure if this is the right definition, it might always be range [min(x,y), max(x,y)] unless x = y " , you mean that  besides meet (1,2)=[1,2], meet (2,3)=[2,3]  ...meet(x,x+1)=[x,x+1],  maybe we can also do the meet like meet (1,3)=[1,3],  meet (3,6)=[3,6] ,  meet (100,200)=[100,200] instead of the Bottom , right?

Comment: For the requirement 5, in the first series  "the too-much-theory"  it described that  "2nd CP pass and we assumed i was 0-1 on the backedge on entry and found a 1-2 instead – so lets “fall” to the range 0-2 " ,  however when we apply requirement 5  "meet(a, b) where both a and b are ranges", then result would be Bottom instead of the  range 0-2, so we finish doing the optimization, right?

Comment: @Jacky, this gets too complicated for comments. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138957/discussion-between-serggr-and-jacky).